# .net atomic operation with an external dll

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

In my .net application, i need to use an external dll that was provided to me as "close box".
I can't access or modify the dll.

I know that it has its own transaction. 
The problem is that when i call the dll methods i can't pass my connection/transaction to them. But my application's operations on the db must be atomic with the dll operation.

Both, my application and the dll work on the same database.

There is a way to resolve this without use the `TransactionScope`?
And, if the answer is no, is `TransactionScope` at the state of the art a good solution?

**UPDATE**

I tried with the `TransactionScope`:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseInfo.Instance.GetConnectionString(connectionStr))
    {
        var sqlQuery = "select * from TEST_TABLE";

        using (var dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var a = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

But on the `connection.Open()` i received this error:
*New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator.*

**UPDATE 2**

I solved the error adding `OLE DB Services = -7` (equivalent at enlist = false in SqlConnection) at the end of the connection string. In this way I disable the pooling, the enlistment, and the cursor services.
But now the problem is that the transaction is committed anyway, even if the  `transactionScope.Complete()` is not reached when an exception is thrown.

Comment: From SQL Server 2008 onwards, using the *exact same connection string* when opening a new connection in a `TransactionScope` will not cause the transaction to be upgraded to a distributed transaction, but I think that will only work for `SqlConnection`, not `OleDbConnection`. If you got `TransactionScope` to work, it's likely you'd end up with a distributed transaction as soon as you mix in the library (assuming it does not create a new `TransactionScope` itself). Distributed transactions can be made to work (with some effort) but it's typically a pain.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i don't understand what you mean with *exact same connection string*?

Comment: I mean that if two `SqlConnection` instances are created in one `TransactionScope`, and they use the same connection string (character for character), then SQL Server can include them in one transaction without involving the distributed transaction coordinator. But, as I said, I don't think this works for `OleDbConnection`.

Comment: If you disable transaction enlistment, then yes, of course the transaction scope is ignored! If you do that you have no transaction in the first place. You'll have to bite the bullet and get it working *with* enlistment (if possible).